# Geometric interpretation of First order condition

Tags: linear-algebra

$f$ is convex if and only if $f(y) \geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x)$ for every $x,y \in dom f$. 
[image]

Im trying to learn about convex optimization and the above theorem is in my book. Since im not good with linear algebra I can not understand this inequality well. Specially I dont understand the  term $(y-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture you've drawn illustrates the meaning of the inequality quite will. The set of $y$ described by the rhs of the inequlity is the plane (line in 1 dimension) which is tangent to the graph of the function passing through $f(x)$. Convexity means that the graph of $f$ lies above this plane and touches it in $f(x)$ (Strict convexity means it touches only in $f(x)$.

This explanation is, strictly speaking valid only if $f$ is once differentiable, since only then you will know for sure you have a tangent plane, but also for general convex $f$ the meaning of the inequality is simply that the graph of $f$ lies on one side of a certain plane passing throug $f(x)$